# Длинная арифметика для работы с большими числами

Tags: c++, олимпиада

Решаю задачу на [E-Olymp](http://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/637).

Мой код:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double n, kol = 1, sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; i < (n*n); i++)
    {
        sum += kol;
        kol *= 2;
    }
    printf("%.0f\n", sum);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Сайт проверяет на входное значение 10. `double`, как я понял, для этого не помощник ибо ограничен. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать?

Comment: В столбик в школе перемножать числа Вас не учили? Вот прямо так алгоритм перемножения двух чисел и расписываете. А результат записываете ввиде обычной строки.

Comment: Сменить язык на джаву для этой задачи...

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/big_integer

Comment: @Qwertiy А что Java даст?

Comment: @MaxZS, там есть BigInteger встроенный.

Comment: Да, ещё формулу желательно упростить.

Comment: Зачем только там цикл?... Это же 2^(n^2)-1, не более того... Т.е. число 11111...111 - всего n*n единиц. Сами сообразите, как вывести в десятичном виде, или нет? :)

Comment: Кстати, там же N до 100 может быть... Вобщем, 3011-значное число придется выводить.

Comment: @Harry Вот именно ... и еще не известно, что дешевле, перемножать в десятичной системе или переводить в десятичную из двоичной ...

Comment: @Mike перемножать в десятичной дешевле, конечно же. Потому что перевод в десятичную требует либо длинного деления, либо перемножения в десятичной...

Comment: @PavelMayorov Перевод обратным double dabble не требует ни деления ни умножения, если что :)

Comment: @Mike и чем он отличается от изначального подсчета в десятичной системе? :)

Answer (score 2):

Из принципа пришлось решить задачу, прошла, даже - просвистела на второе место :) очень быстро.

Мы точно можем оценить максимальный размер числа, так что знаем, какой массив данных нам понадобится. Я пошел по пути `N*N` удвоений, с последующим вычитанием 1. Нам нужны только две операции - удвоение и вычитание 1. Берем массив в 350 (с запасом) `unsigned long`, и `N*N` раз удваиваем (суммируем соответствующие элементы, выполняем, если надо, перенос). Чтоб быстрей потом преобразовывать в десятичное - в каждом элементе массива значения ограничены одним миллиардом. Отслеживаю размер числа - чтоб не суммировать лишнее...

Я, конечно, могу привести тут код, но не уверен, насколько это хорошо в смысле педагогическом :) Чуть-чуть покажу все же.

```
class bigNum
{
public:
    bigNum() { a[0] = 1; }
    void mul2();
    void dec() { a[0]--; }
    void out();

private:
    static const int size = 350;
    static const int lim  = 1000000000;
    unsigned long a[size] = { 0 };
    int last = 1;
};

void bigNum::mul2()
{
    unsigned long carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < last; ++i)
    {
        a[i] *= 2;
        a[i] += carry;
        if (a[i] >= lim)
        {
            carry = a[i]/lim;
            a[i] %= lim;
        }
        else carry = 0;
    }
    if (carry)
    {
        a[last++] = carry;
    }
};
```

P.S. Для подъема скорости можно множить, скажем, на 16 или там 64, соответствующим образом меняя размеры...

Comment: `dec()` не будет работать, если `a[0] == 0`

Comment: @int3 По условию задачи - `2^N-1` - это невозможно, не правда ли? :)

Comment: класс всё-таки называется `bigNum`, а не `solver` ;) Для задачи не принципиально, да

Comment: Условный оператор в цикле - лишний, только замедляет. Но, вообще говоря, тут надо тогда уж использовать быстрое возведение в степень...

Comment: В быстром возведении в степень есть произведение длинных целых. Простейший алгоритм для которого квадратичный. Получится решение за квадрат. Так оно и сейчас за квадрат, только проще, значит константа меньше.